# Multiple Array Passing with SpriteKit - UIColor and String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, uicolor

I have three data view controllers: settingsVC.swift, menuVC.swift and GameScene.swift

I am attempting to use a prepareforsegue method for the transfer of [UIColor] and [String] array's from settings to menuVC and then another transfer from menuVC to GameScene.swift using a instantiateViewController. I have declared empty arrays in each and just want to pass data from one page to another and am receiving 'use of unresolved identifier' on both of my arrays. Any help is appreciated.

```
class MenuVC: UIViewController {

var colourSettingsMenu = [UIColor]()
var otherSettingsMenu = [String]()

//action function for button to transfer to a 1 player game
@IBAction func Player1Game(_ sender: MenuVC) {
    moveToGame(game: .player1, colourSettings: colourSettingsMenu, otherSettings: otherSettingsMenu)
}

//action function for button to transfer to a 2 player game
@IBAction func Player2Game(_ sender: MenuVC) {
    moveToGame(game: .player2, colourSettings: colourSettingsMenu, otherSettings: otherSettingsMenu)
}


func moveToGame(game : gameType, colourSettings: [UIColor], otherSettings: [String]) {
    let GameVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameVC") as! GameViewController

    currentGameType = game
    colourSettingsGame.GameVC = colourSettings;
    otherSettingsGame.GameVC = otherSettings;
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(GameVC, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func moveToSettings(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "settings", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "settings") {
        let SettingsVC = segue.destination as! SettingsVC
        SettingsVC.colourSettings = colourSettingsMenu
        SettingsVC.otherSettings = otherSettingsMenu
    }

}
```

}

```
class SettingsVC : UIViewController {

//Colours for segue transfer
var player1Colour: UIColor?
var player2Colour: UIColor?
var ballColour: UIColor?

// other settings to allow segue transfer
// do we need these
var AIDiff: String?
var paddleSi: String?
var ballSi: String?

//arrays for segue transfer
var colourSettings = [UIColor]()
var otherSettings = [String]()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {
    let colourSettings = [player1Colour, player2Colour, ballColour]
    let otherSettings = [AIDiff, paddleSi, ballSi]

    if (segue.identifier == "back") {
        let MenuVC = segue.destination as! MenuVC
        MenuVC.colourSettingsMenu = colourSettings as! [UIColor]
        MenuVC.otherSettingsMenu = otherSettings as! [String]
    }
```

}

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

 // init colour settings array
 var colourSettingsGame = [UIColor]()
 // init other settings array
 var otherSettingsGame = [String]()

 var currentGameType = gameType?.self
 }
```

Comment: Not clear where does the error appears... Tell us more, which line? which class?

Comment: MenuVC: (1) - Value of type '[UIColor]' has no member 'GameVC'
                (2) - Value of type '[String]' has no member 'GameVC'
GameViewController.swift (1) - 'gameType' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initialisers
GameScene.swift (1/2/3) - Use of unresolved identifier 'currentGameType'
                              (4) - Use of unresolved identifier 'settings'

Comment: Correct that first! UIColor has no member GameVC... Your types are wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should not name a variable like a class name , here

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {
if (segue.identifier == "settings") {
      let nextSettings = segue.destination as! SettingsVC
      nextSettings.colourSettings = colourSettingsMenu
      nextSettings.otherSettings = otherSettingsMenu
  }

}
```

and here

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {
   let colourSettings = [player1Colour, player2Colour, ballColour]
   let otherSettings = [AIDiff, paddleSi, ballSi]

  if (segue.identifier == "back") {
     let nexrMenu = segue.destination as! MenuVC
     nexrMenu.colourSettingsMenu = colourSettings as! [UIColor]
     nexrMenu.otherSettingsMenu = otherSettings as! [String]
 }
```